# How to target this button in the if condition in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, this, toggle

I have several buttons with the same class that toggle dropdown lists, the lists are closed if the user clicks somewhere outside the button, but if the user clicks on the other button with the same class, the list belonging to the previously clicked button stays open, how can I change this so that if the user clicks on any other button other than "this" - the other list closes? (What I'm trying to do is to change the if condition to something like if (!event.target.matches this ('.dropdown-btn')) )

```
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropdown-btn">
    Pirkt tiešsaistē
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-list">
      ...
    </div>
```

```
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction(obj) {
  obj.classList.toggle("dropdown-btn-active");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropdown-btn')) {
    var dropdownBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('dropdown-show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('dropdown-show');
      }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all buttons and bind `addEventListener` every, in it use function to clear all active classes and add active class to current item.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (!e.target.closest('.dropdown-btn-active')) {
    clearBtns();
  }
  e.target.classList.toggle("dropdown-btn-active");
}));

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropdown-btn')) {
     clearBtns();
  }
}

function clearBtns() {
  let dropdownBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdownBtns.length; i++) {
      let openDropdown = dropdownBtns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('dropdown-btn-active')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('dropdown-btn-active');
      }      
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-btn-active {
  background: #ff0;
}
.dropdown-list {
  display: none;
}
.dropdown-btn-active + .dropdown-list {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="dropdown-btn">
    Pirkt tiešsaistē
</button>
<div class="dropdown-list">
  First
</div>
<button class="dropdown-btn">
    Pirkt tiešsaistē
</button>
<div class="dropdown-list">
  Two
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).